# How to add comments to folder in linux and view them with mouse cursor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, ubuntu-14.04, directory

I run simulations for various choices of parameters. For each choice I store the resulting data in a folder, like

```
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/C=10/1.dat 
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/C=10/2.dat 
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/C=10/3.dat
```

...
and

```
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/C=20/1.dat 
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/C=20/2.dat 
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/C=20/3.dat
```

...and so forth.

would like to write a little text file AAA.txt which contains not just the C parameter but all the others too. Then when viewing this folder which contains the data I want to hold my cursor on the little file symbol and have a little box appear. This box should show just the content of AAA.txt, so I can quickly check which set of parameters was used in this particular run.

Anyone know how to do this? I use Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of ways to give you a custom "tooltip". As an alternative, you could look into creating *custom* thumbnails of your .dat files.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157849/is-it-possible-to-preview-arbitrary-formats-in-nautilus) for how to do that with *nautilus*; the default file browser for Ubuntu.

Alternatively, you might look into what [Gloobus](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/quick-file-previewer-gloobus-preview.html) can do for you.